# Django aggregation and following foreign key relations

Tags: python, django

Models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # More stuff.
class Sale(models.Model):
    sale_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    # More stuff.
```

View:

```
class TodaySales(ListView):
    # Stuff in here.
    def get_queryset(self):
        sales_today = Sale.objects.filter(sale_date=date.today())
        return sales_today.values('item').annotate(Count('item'))
```

I get back something like this:

```
[{'item': 1, 'item__count': 2}, {'item': 2, 'item__count': 1}]
```

This is nice and all and but what I really want is to be able to get extra information about the item, such as its name, etc. But I can't seem to do this easily since all I get is the item ID, so I can't in my template do, for example, {{ item.name }}.

Is there some good way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will do. Try:

```
Item.objects.filter(
    sale__sale_date=date.today()
).annotate(
    count = Count('sale')
)
```

Answer (score 4):

As you care about getting extra data from the Item, rather than the Sale, you could query on that class:

```
models.Item.objects.filter(sale__sale_date=date.today()).annotate(Count('id'))
```

That returns ORM objects, rather than `values` or a `values_list`: you'll also have a synthetic `id__count` attribute available with the sale count for that particular item.

Alternatively, if you know ahead of time exactly which fields you want, you can also name them explicitly in your `values` invocation, e.g.:

```
sales_today.values('item', 'item__name').annotate(Count('item'))
```